# Change the value of a field in multiple documents within a collection based on a condition (using Firebase/Flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named 'users' and within this collection, I simply want to change the value of a field in multiple documents based on a condition. Within the 'users' collection there's a field named 'username' which has 400 users with each value being as such:

user1,
user2,
user3,
...
user400

The goal is to change the value of each field where the username is between user1 and user50. In other words, user1-user50 should have their values changed while user51-user400 should not have any changes. Can this be achieved?

The code below is an example of how to change all values of a field in the users collection but that's not exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you for any help!

```
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get().then((snapshot) {
        for (DocumentSnapshot ds in snapshot.docs) {
          ds.reference.update({field: value});
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. What you should do is create a separate query for each interval. For example, if you need to update user1-user50, then you should use a query in which you should order the results by the `username` field and then call [Query#startAt(user1)](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/startAt.html) and [Query#endAt(user50)](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/endAt.html).

There is something that you should also notice. The `username` field is of type String. This means that when you order strings, the documents that are read are ordered [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). So you might not get the desired results. However, you can simply solve this problem. Instead of storing the user name as a string, you can simply store the number. The username without the `user` prefix. In this way, you'll get the correct results using:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
                          .orderBy('username')
                          .startAt('user1')
                          .endAt('user50')
                          .get()
```